# C# WinForms: How to enforce the DataGridView to bind its data from the data source

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a windows form that contains a gridView for some orders.

I aimed to have a constructor of the form that takes an order ID, and the constructor will be responsible for selecting that order in the gridView.

but I've noticed that the gridView -while the execution of code is in the constructor- is empty! although the InitialComponents() had invoked!

so, I want a way to enforce the gridView (or the dataSource) to bind their data (like the DataBind() method in web forms)

I know that I can achieve my goal in many ways, but I want this way to be used to improve my DataBinding information.

The dataSource type is ObjectDataSource and the object is LinqDataContext.

thanks..

Comment: store the Id in a field and Select in the Load event.

Comment: Yeas I have this idea in my mind, thank you, but I'm angry and want to know how to solve that issue :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a BindingSource object? If not, are you setting both:
(1) DataSource
(2) DataMember
appropriately?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using BindingSource, the dataBinding is done but not in the constructor time, it's done after that somewhere. And I want to enforce the databinding in the constructor

Comment: Would you have any issue if you databind in the Load event?

Comment: hmmm I hoped to make my code as professional as I can, and I feel my self not that professional when I declare a field for holding the id temporary and then pass it to the Load event, but I will do that because there is no other way I think :( thanks @Arun for your help

Comment: Why do you need to pass in an ID?